# Show boot process on screen

Tags: adb, nexus-4, boot, stock-android, logging

I've borked something in my nexus 4 stock rom playing with system files over ADB, and my device no longer boots past the animation.

Is there any way I can make the system show it's boot process instead of the animation? Or at least a way to enable adb at this stage so i can logcat and try to identify the problem

I still can do whatever I want with the device - I have cwm and the device is unlocked but I'd prefer to fix the problem instead of backing up my files through adb for hours and reflashing stock rom

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried this app from Chainfire?

https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=eu.chainfire.liveboot

From the description, it shows a logcat of the boot process over the boot animation.

Comment: Yeah, I can't really install an app before I boot into the system.. That's the whole problem. I'm looking more for a solution involving some modification to android files allowing me to do something similar to this.

Comment: Oh yeah. Missed that part!